# How does printing work in Java

Tags: java

I am doing Java for the first time at a college. I'm struggling with the printing to work. I am unable to print, or let the program to print anything at all. I think the issue is in the display methods, but can't figure it out for the life of me.  So after all the comments below I have made the changes, however I am now getting it that it only prints the headers in each method, and gives the following error when I try to add an additional event to the array.

#### Add Events:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at JavaAssignment1.TestEvent.addEvents(TestEvent.java:207)
at JavaAssignment1.TestEvent.main(TestEvent.java:28)
```

#### TestEvent.java:

```
package JavaAssignment1;

import java.util.Scanner;

import firstPrograms.My;
import firstPrograms.MyDate;
import firstPrograms.MyTime;

public class TestEvent 
{
public static Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //int noOfEvents = 25;
    int option = 0;

    Event [] allEvents = new Event [25];

    do
    {
        option = mainMenu(option);

        switch (option)
        {
            case 1:
                addEvents(allEvents);
            break;

            case 2:
                displayEvents(allEvents);
            break;

            case 3:
                //System.out.println("\nEnter Search criteria here");
                do
                {
                    option = searchMenu(option);

                    switch (option)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            //addEventsByEventNo(allEvents);
                            System.out.println("\nEnter Search criteria here");
                        break;

                        case 2:
                            //displayEventsByEventDate(allEvents);
                            System.out.println("\nEnter Search criteria here");
                        break;

                        case 3:
                            //displayEventsByEventCategory(allEvents);
                            System.out.println("\nEnter Search criteria here");
                        break;

                        case 4:
                            //displayIncomes(allEvents);
                        break;

                        //case 5:
                        //  displayCategoryIncomes(allEvents);

                        //break;

                        //case 6:
                            //System.out.println("\nGoodbye");
                    }

                }while (option != 4);
            break;

            case 4:
                displayIncomes(allEvents);
            break;

            case 5:
                displayCategoryIncomes(allEvents);

            break;

            case 6:
                System.out.println("\nGoodbye");
        }

    }while (option != 6);

}

public int createArray(Event [] allEvents)
{
    allEvents[0] = new Event (1000, "West Ham United v Arsenal", "Premiership", new MyDate (9, 03, 2016),  new MyDate (9, 04, 2016), new MyTime (12, 45, 00), "Upton Park", 3500, 3498, 65.00, 0.025);
    allEvents[1] = new Event (1001, "Sunderland v Arsenal", "Premiership", new MyDate (24, 03, 2016),  new MyDate (24, 04, 2016), new MyTime (14, 05, 00), "Stadium of Light", 500, 500, 75.00, 0.05);
    allEvents[2] = new Event (1002, "Arsenal v Crystal Palace", "Premiership", new MyDate (17, 03, 2016),  new MyDate (17, 04, 2016), new MyTime (16, 05, 00), "Emirates Stadium", 100, 98, 125.00, 0.025);
    allEvents[3] = new Event (1003,"Arsenal v West Bromwich Albion", "Premiership", new MyDate (21, 03, 2016),  new MyDate (21, 04, 2016), new MyTime (19, 45, 00), "Emirates Stadium", 125, 72, 95.00, 0.025);
    allEvents[4] = new Event (1004, "Arsenal v Norwich City", "Premiership", new MyDate (30, 03, 2016),  new MyDate (30, 04, 2016), new MyTime (17, 30, 00), "Emirates Stadium", 1250, 1137, 110, 0.025);
    allEvents[5] = new Event (1005, "Manchester City v Arsenal", "Premiership", new MyDate (8, 04, 2016),  new MyDate (8, 05, 2016), new MyTime (16, 05, 00), "Etihad Stadium", 5000, 4796, 75.00, 0.05);
    allEvents[6] = new Event (1006, "Arsenal v Aston Villa", "Premiership", new MyDate (15, 04, 2016),  new MyDate (15, 05, 2016), new MyTime (19, 30, 00), "Emirates Stadium", 1250, 872, 16.00, 0.025);
    allEvents[7] = new Event (1007, "MLS All-Stars v Arsenal", "Friendly", new MyDate (28, 01, 2016),  new MyDate (28, 07, 2016), new MyTime (17, 00, 00), "Avaya Stadium", 500, 391, 75.00, 0.05);
    allEvents[8] = new Event (1008, "Chivas de Guadalajara v Arsenal", "Friendly", new MyDate (31, 01, 2016),  new MyDate (31, 07, 2016), new MyTime (19, 30, 00), "StubHub Center", 1250, 872, 16.00, 0.025);
    allEvents[9] = new Event (1009, "West Ham United v Manchester United", "Cup", new MyDate (13, 03, 2016),  new MyDate (13, 04, 2016), new MyTime (19, 00, 00), "Upton Park", 750, 615, 85.00, 0.075);
    allEvents[10] = new Event (1010, "Everton v TBC (West Ham or Man United)", "Cup", new MyDate (14, 04, 2016),  new MyDate (23, 04, 2016), new MyTime (17, 15, 00), "Wembley Stadium", 10000, 5000, 150.00, 0.015);
    allEvents[11] = new Event (1011, "Crystal Palace v Watford", "Cup", new MyDate (24, 03, 2016),  new MyDate (24, 04, 2016), new MyTime (16, 00, 00), "Wembley Stadium", 10000, 10000, 150.00, 0.015);
    allEvents[12] = new Event (1012, "FA Cup Final - TBC", "Cup", new MyDate (25, 04, 2016),  new MyDate (21, 05, 2016), new MyTime (15, 00, 00), "Wembley Stadium", 20000, 0, 150.00, 0.015);
    allEvents[13] = new Event (1013, "UEFA Champions League Final - TBC", "Europe", new MyDate (5, 5, 2016),  new MyDate (28, 05, 2016), new MyTime (19, 45, 00), "Stadio Giuseppe Meazza", 25000, 0, 350.00, 0.01);
    allEvents[14] = new Event (1014, "UEFA Europa League Final - TBC", "Europe", new MyDate (6, 05, 2016),  new MyDate (18, 05, 2016), new MyTime (19, 45, 00), "St. Jakob-Park", 20000, 0, 250.00, 0.015);

    return 16;
}

public static int mainMenu(int option)
{
    int tempOption = 0;

    System.out.println("Event Menu");
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
    System.out.println("1 - Add Event");
    System.out.println("2 - Display All Events");
    System.out.println("3 - Search Events");
    System.out.println("4 - Display Incomes for Events");
    System.out.println("5 - Display Incomes by Category");
    System.out.println("6 - Exit");
    System.out.println("Enter Option (1 - 6): ");
    tempOption = key.nextInt();
    key.nextLine();

    return tempOption;
}

public static int searchMenu(int option)
{
    int tempOption = 0;

    System.out.println("Event Menu");
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
    System.out.println("1 - Search By Event No");
    System.out.println("2 - Search By Date");
    System.out.println("3 - Search By Category");
    //System.out.println("4 - Display Incomes for Events");
    //System.out.println("5 - Display Incomes by Category");
    System.out.println("4 - Previous Menu");
    System.out.println("Enter Option (1 - 4): ");
    tempOption = key.nextInt();
    key.nextLine();

    return tempOption;
}

public int option(int min, int max)
{
    int input;
    boolean valid;


    do
    { 
        valid = false;
        input = key.nextInt();

        if (input < min || input > max)
        {            
            System.out.printf("\n\n%s%d%s%d%s", "Invalid input! Please re-enter a value between ", min, " and ", max, ":  ");   
        }
        else
        {
            valid = true;
            //System.out.printf("\n\n%s%d%s%d%s%d", "Number entered ", input, " is between ", min, " & ", max); 
        }

    } while (!valid);

    return input;
}

private static void displayEvents(Event [] allEvents)
{
    System.out.println("\nEvents:");

    for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++)
    {
        if(allEvents[i] != null)
        System.out.printf("\n\n\t" + allEvents.toString());
    }


}

private static void addEvents (Event[] allEvents)
{
    System.out.println("\nAdd Events:");

    int day = 0, month = 0, year = 0;
    MyDate tempSaleDate;
    MyDate tempEventDate;
    int hour = 0, mins = 0, secs = 0;
    MyTime tempTime;
    boolean answer = false;
    String keyedAnswer = "";



    for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++)
    {   
        Event[] newEvent = null;

        newEvent[i] = new Event();

        allEvents[i].setEventNo((allEvents[allEvents.length - 1]).getEventNo() + 1);

        System.out.println("\n\tPlease enter event name for event: ");
        allEvents[i].setEventName(key.nextLine());
        System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's category: ");
        allEvents[i].setCategory(key.nextLine());
        System.out.println("\tPlease enter event location: ");
        allEvents[i].setVenue(key.nextLine());
        System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's tickets date of sale (ie 1 - 31): ");
        day = key.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's tickets month of sale (ie 1 - 12): ");
        month = key.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's tickets year of sale (ie 2016): ");
        year = key.nextInt();
        tempSaleDate =  new MyDate(day, month, year);
        allEvents[i].setDateOnSale(tempSaleDate);
        key.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's date of event (ie 1 - 31): ");
        day = key.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's month of event (ie 1 - 12): ");
        month = key.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's year of event (ie 2016): ");
        year = key.nextInt();
        tempEventDate = new MyDate(day, month, year);
        allEvents[i].setEventDate(tempEventDate);
        key.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's start hour (ie 1am = 1, 10am = 10, 10pm = 22, etc): ");
        hour = key.nextInt(); 
        key.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's  start minutes (ie = 00, 15, 30, 45, etc): ");
        mins = key.nextInt();
        key.nextLine();
        tempTime = new MyTime(hour, mins, secs);
        allEvents[i].setEventTime(tempTime);
        System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's ticket allocation: ");
        allEvents[i].setTicketsReceived(key.nextInt());
        key.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\tPlease enter the amount of tickets sold for the event: ");                    
        allEvents[i].setTicketsSold(key.nextInt());
        key.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's ticket cost: £");
        allEvents[i].setTicketCost(key.nextDouble());
        key.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\tPlease enter the event's ticket commission rate: ");
        allEvents[i].setCommissionRate(key.nextDouble());
        key.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\n\t\tWould you like to add another event (Y / N): ");
        keyedAnswer = key.nextLine();
        //System.out.println("\n\tKeyed Answer = " + keyedAnswer);

        if (answer = keyedAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
        {
            answer = false;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            answer = true;
        }
    }
}

public static void displayIncomes(Event[] allEvents)
{   
    System.out.println("\n\nIncome per event");
    System.out.println("\n\n\tEvent No" + "\t\tEvent" + "\t\t\t\tActual Income" + "\t\t\t\tPotential Income");

    for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++)
    {
        if(allEvents[i] != null)
        System.out.println("\n\n\t" + allEvents[i].getEventNo() + "\t\t" + allEvents[i].getEventName() + "\t\t\t£" + allEvents[i].getActualIncome() + "\t\t\t£" + allEvents[i].getPotentialIncome());
    }   
}

public static void displayCategoryIncomes(Event[] allEvents)
{
    double tempActualIncome = 0.00, totalTemp = 0.00;
    double percentageAchieved = 0.00;
    String tempCategory;

    System.out.println("\n\nIncome Per Category:");
    System.out.println("\n\n\tCategory" + "\t\t\t\tActual Income" + "\t\t\tPecentage of Income Achieved");

    for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++)
    {
        //if(allEvents[i] != null)
        //{
            //if (allEvents[i].getCategory() == "Premiership")
            //if ("Premiership".equals(allEvents[i].getCategory()))
            if (allEvents[i] != null && "Premiership".equals(allEvents[i].getCategory()))
            {
                //double tempActualIncome = 0.00;
                //double percentageAchieved = 0.00;
                //String tempCategory;

                tempActualIncome = allEvents[i].getActualIncome();
                totalTemp += tempActualIncome;
                percentageAchieved = (tempActualIncome / allEvents[i].getPotentialIncome()) * 100;
                tempCategory = "Premiership";

                System.out.printf("%s%s%s%.2f%s%.2f", "\n\t", tempCategory, "\t\t\t\t£", totalTemp, "\t\t\t\t", percentageAchieved);
            }
            //else if (allEvents [i].getCategory() == "Friendly")
            else if ("Friendly".equals(allEvents[i].getCategory()))
            {
                //double tempActualIncome = 0.00;
                //double percentageAchieved = 0.00;
                //String tempCategory;

                tempActualIncome += allEvents[i].getActualIncome();
                percentageAchieved = (tempActualIncome / allEvents[i].getPotentialIncome()) * 100;
                tempCategory = "Friendly";

                //System.out.println("\n\n\t" + tempCategory + "\t\t\t£" + tempActualIncome);
                System.out.printf("%s%s%s%.2f%s%.2f", "\n\t", tempCategory, "\t\t\t\t£", tempActualIncome, "\t\t\t\t", percentageAchieved);
            }

            //else if (allEvents [i].getCategory() == "Cup")
            else if ("Cup".equals(allEvents[i].getCategory()))
            {
                //double tempActualIncome = 0.00;
                //double percentageAchieved = 0.00;
                //String tempCategory;

                tempActualIncome += allEvents[i].getActualIncome();
                percentageAchieved = (tempActualIncome / allEvents[i].getPotentialIncome()) * 100;
                tempCategory = "Cup";

                System.out.println("\n\n\t" + tempCategory + "\t\t\t£" + tempActualIncome);
            }

            //else if (allEvents [i].getCategory() == "Europe")
            else if ("Europe".equals(allEvents[i].getCategory()))
            {
                //double tempActualIncome = 0.00;
                //double percentageAchieved = 0.00;
                //String tempCategory;

                tempActualIncome += allEvents[i].getActualIncome();
                percentageAchieved = (tempActualIncome / allEvents[i].getPotentialIncome()) * 100;
                tempCategory = "Europe";

                System.out.println("\n\n\t" + tempCategory + "\t\t\t£" + tempActualIncome);
            }

    }
    //}
    //for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++)
    //{
        //System.out.println("\n\n\t" + allEvents[i].getCategory()+ "\t\t\t£" + allEvents[i].getActualIncome() + "\t\t\t£" + allEvents[i].getPotentialIncome());

    //}
}



}
```

Comment: Test string equality with `String.equals()` instead of `==`

Comment: What does `My.p(String)` do? If you want to print something, you could try to use `System.out.print(String)`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. 
Please look at  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: please add your stack trace please ??

Comment: My.p was a practice method in a class called My all it does is print instead of using the System.out.print(String) method, I have changed all the My.p to the System method

Comment: Hi Vikrant, I am not sure what a stack trace is exactly.  Could you explain what it is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

Strings are compared with `equals` method

```
allEvents[i].getCategory() == "Premiership"
```

```
"Premiership".equals(allEvents[i].getCategory())
```

You have used a lot of `static` methods that aren't necessary to run the application. In the typical console application only `main` method should be static. You should create objects, and use it's methods and properties even in the same class.

`==` means that Objects are equal, has the same reference. It is only achievable if you use static constants like

```
public static final String PERMSHIP = "Premiership";
```

and use it everywhere in the code, but it's very bad practice.

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks for the help.  When I try to execute this it is throwing the following error - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at JavaAssignment1.TestEvent.displayCategoryIncomes(TestEvent.java:263)
 at JavaAssignment1.TestEvent.main(TestEvent.java:64)

Comment: What the line it is?

Comment: when I take static out from them the compiler gives an error to change back to static

Comment: the error on line 263 refers to if ("Premiership".equals(allEvents[i].getCategory())), the error on line 64 refers to case 5:
     displayCategoryIncomes(allEvents);
     
    break;

Comment: allEvents[i] is null, add a check for null first. if (allEvents[i] != null && "Premiership".equals(allEvents[i].getCategory())). You can fix nullpointer exception, but there's a reason you got it, because you didn't initialize an array. Use arraylist instead.

Comment: if(allEvents[i] != null) I added this to try and get it to print, the items in the array don't seem to be printing though

Comment: I have never used arraylist before, so not sure what way it works.

Comment: is it possible to add to the arrays of this nature, ie in my case add new events to it?

Comment: arrays are fixed length, if it riches a cap you have to recreate the array to add additional space and copy its contents. The arraylist has no limited size and better convert em to this.

Answer (score 0):

Use "System.out.println" not System.out.printf

Answer (score 0):

Euh how can you compile your code this will not work

```
Event [] allEvents = new Event [noOfEvents];
public static int createArray(Event [] allEvents){
   allEvents[0] = new Event (1000, "West Ham United v Arsenal", "Premiership", new MyDate (9, 03, 2016),  new MyDate (9, 04, 2016), new MyTime (12, 45, 00), "Upton Park", 3500, 3498, 65.00, 0.025);
...
```

When you specify allEvents[0] compiler doesn't know if you want to modify this.allEvents[0] or parameter value

What is

```
My.p(String value)
```

Does it works to print a String use

```
System.out.print(String valueToPrint)
```

Or

```
System.out.println(String valueToPrint)
```

The secund one adds '\n' at the end of String to print

Useful option in parameters here you don't use it in your function

```
public static int mainMenu(int option)
{
    int tempOption = 0;

    My.p("\n\nEvent Menu");
    My.p("\n----------------------------");
    My.p("\n1 - Add Event");
    My.p("\n2 - Display All Events");
    My.p("\n3 - Search Events");
    My.p("\n4 - Display Incomes for Events");
    My.p("\n5 - Display Incomes by Category");
    My.p("\n6 - Exit");
    My.p("\nEnter Option (1 - 6): ");
    tempOption = key.nextInt();
    key.nextLine();

    return tempOption;
}
```

`allEvents [i].getCategory() == "Cup"` this doesn't works category is a String

best practices :

`"Cup".equals(allEvents[i].getCategory())`

And for the end

```
 for (int i = 0; i < allEvents.length(); i++)
    {
        //if(allEvents[i] != null)
        System.out.printf("\n\n\t" + allEvents.toString());
    }
```

I don't like printf prefere print or println but if you want to use printf do it this way

```
System.out.printf("\n\n\t%s", allEvents.toString());
```

- %s : String
- %d : decimal
- %f : float

Comment: This won't work
System.out.printf("\n\nNumber entered " + input + " is between " + min + " & " + max);

 System.out.printf("\n\n\t" + allEvents.toString());

This will work


System.out.printf("\n\n\t%s" + allEvents.toString());
System.out.printf("\n\n%s %d %s %d %s %d", Number entered ", input, " is between, min , " & ", max);

or best parctice

System.out.println("\n\nNumber entered " + input + " is between " + min + " & " + max);

 System.out.println("\n\n\t" + allEvents.toString());

Comment: This code was meant to help validate the menu. public int option(int min, int max)
    {
       int input;
       boolean valid;
    do
    { 
        valid = false;
        input = key.nextInt();
        if (input < min || input > max)
        {            
            System.out.printf("\n\nInvalid input! Please re-enter a value between " + min + " and " + max + ":  "); 
        }
        else
        {
            valid = true;
            System.out.printf("\n\nNumber entered " + input + " is between " + min + " & " + max);  
        }
    } while (!valid);
    return input;
}